# Как очистить "/var/spool/exim4/db/retry" на Debian 7

Tags: linux, debian, администрирование, exim

```
root@debian1:~# du -sh /var/spool/exim4/db/retry
1.1G    /var/spool/exim4/db/retry

root@debian1:~# exim_tidydb /var/spool/exim4 retry
Tidying Exim hints database /var/spool/exim4/db/retry
Tidying complete

root@debian1:~# du -sh /var/spool/exim4/db/retry
1.1G    /var/spool/exim4/db/retry
```

Что можно **без последствий** предпринять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man exim_tidydb`: без дополнительных опций удаляются записи старше 30 дней.

с помощью опции `-t время` можно указать другую точку «отсечения».

например, для удаления записей старше 7 дней:

```
$ sudo exim_tidydb -t 7d /var/spool/exim4 retry
```

Comment: Спасибо, выполнил с параметрами `-t 1d, 2d, 7d, 15d`, но, к сожалению, размер файла не изменился.

Comment: 1. возможно, база данных разрослась записями за последний день. 2. возможно, имеет смысл перезапустить *exim*. 3. в крайнем случае, если эта база данных очень вам мешает, остановите *exim*, удалите файл с базой данных и снова запустите *exim*.

Comment: Удалить и перезапустить - это решение подошло, файл потом снова появился